# Mutual authentication via SSL Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, ssl

I configure mutual authentication via SSL between client (Windows 7) and server (Windows Server 2008 R2). I create wallet via Oracle Wallet Manager (OWM) both on client and server, then  I create certificate requests for client and server in OWM, as it's shown in image below.[image: Certificate request via OWM]

I create CA-certificate in OpenSSL according to:

```
openssl> genrsa -out root.key 2048 
openssl> req -x509 -new -key root.key -days 1000 -out root.crt
```

Then I create sertificate request:

```
openssl> genrsa -out serv.key 2048
openssl> req -new –key serv.key –out serv.csr
```

Further I copy contents of cerfiticate request from OWM to *.csr file, that was created via OpenSSL, create sertificate from this file and sign it with CA certificate.

```
openssl> x509 -req –in serv.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out serv.crt -days 500
```

Similary, I create a client certificate and sign it with CA certificate. Next, I import CA-certificate to OWM via "Import Trusted Certificate" both in client and server and a client or server sertificate via "Import User Certificate" on client or server-machine accordingly. Then save wallets and set "Auto Login" flag.

Next I create connection via Net Manager -> Local -> Profile -> Oracle Advanced Security -> SSL on both client and server. Listener.ora on server now contains this:

> SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
>
> WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY
> = C:\OraWallet) ) )
>
> LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
> TCP)(HOST = WIN-QV6N8G35RD5.localdomain)(PORT = 1521)) ) (DESCRIPTION
> = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = WIN-QV6N8G35RD5.localdomain)(PORT = 2484)) ) )

Then I add new "TCP/IP with SSL" connection on client and test it, but error appears on client:

> ORA-28864: SSL connection closed gracefully

I made trace on server and there is 2 errors:

> TNS-12560:TNS: protocol adapter error
>
> TNS-00540:SSL protocol adapter failure

Well, now I don't know, how to fix them.

Comment: did you check if your listener is restarted and does listen on port 2484? do your listener log show anything useful? You should enable tracing in your client's `sqlnet.ora` to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Another issue: Does the database user have permissions to read the wallet?

Comment: @jmk, I set "Full access" to Everyone on ewallet.p12 files both on client and server.

`Started with pid=1384
Listening on:  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN-QV6N8G35RD5)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on:  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=WIN-QV6N8G35RD5)(PORT=2484)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start` 
- from listener.log on server, and no errors in file

Comment: Are you on a RAC system with scan listeners as the notification to CRS suggests?

Comment: No, it's Oracle Database 11g  Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: I really think you need to get a full client trace to hunt down the issue, perhaps with Oracle support. You may want to check Note 762286.1 for some hints. Another option would be to temporary disable `SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION` and check if it is an issue with ssl itself or with the certificate based authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved via using orapki for creating wallets and sertificates for client and server. [This manual](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/HOW-TO--Setting-up-Encrypted-Communications-Channels-in-Oracle-Database/) helped me to solve the problem.